# Linux application for reading packets from raw socket stops receiving packets after sometime

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I have written a Linux application program that receives UDP packets transmitted from a Desktop with fixed & known IP-address on the network. I am using a raw socket to receive packets on my system and filter the received packets based on the source address.

The problem I am facing is, the program runs fine for some time and I get all the required packets, but after a couple of hours, the application stops getting any packets. If I run the command,
`tcpdump -i eth0 src 192.168.20.48` on my system, then I see that the system continues to receive the expected packets. But I am not sure what is causing my program to stop receiving packets.

Below is the code snippet used to open a raw socket, receive packets, and filter out the UDP packets transmitted from the known IP address.

```
int main()
{
    int sockfd;
    int one = 1;
    struct timeval tv;
    socklen_t len;
    int bytes;
    unsigned char tsptr[2048];
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
    struct iphdr *iph;
    int result=0;
    char source_add[50];
    char expected_source_add[50];

    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 ) {
      BRH_PERROR("socket creation failed");
      return 1;
    }

    tv.tv_sec = 30;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR|SO_REUSEPORT, &one, sizeof(one));
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(char*)&tv,sizeof(tv));

    strcpy(expected_source_add, "192.168.20.48");

    while (1) {
        /*Read fixed data count from socket*/
        bytes =recvfrom(sockfd, tsptr, 1500, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);

        iph=(struct iphdr*)tsptr;

        //get only UDP packet
        if (iph->protocol != 17) continue;

        strcpy(source_add,inet_ntoa(cliaddr.sin_addr));

        result = strcmp(expected_source_add,source_add);

        /*receive data from expected IP address only*/
        if( result == 0) {
            //Consume the packet
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any clue on why the packet receive stops on my application, even though ***tcpdump*** shows that packets are being received on the interface, will be helpful.

Comment: You don't know where the problem is, but you do know it's not in the code you have removed? Try to create minimal but complete example, which you can paste without removing any lines but still exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code you write here can not see any problem that you describe, I think you should do something like below.
1. using wireshark or tcpdump to see if the nic receive packets successfully
2. beyond the program, do you use any buffer or message queue and are they working good?
3. using tools to see if there exists any memeory leak
4. writing log in every step, especially around recvefrom and strcmp